# Animating the sprite array created from texture atlas

Tags: animation, libgdx, sprite, texture-atlas

I have created a sprite array from texture atlas like this.

```
playerSprite = atlas.createSprites("player");
```

Inside texture atlas, player regions are named as `player01`, `player02` and `player03`.

```
playerAnimation = new Animation(0.5f, playerSprite);
playerAnimation.setPlayMode(PlayMode.NORMAL);
```

and I rendered it like this.

```
batch.draw(playerAnimation.getKeyFrame(animTime,true), ninja.getX(),ninja.getY(),
            ninja.getWidth(),ninja.getHeight());
```

When I execute, this throws an error.

> "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero."

I am getting frustrated on these error,and I already wasted a lot of time on this issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Stack trace:

```
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrameIndex(Animation.java:142)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrame(Animation.java:126)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrame(Animation.java:114)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.drawPlayer(GameScreen.java:254)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.batchDraw(GameScreen.java:229)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:115)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

I tried with textureregion also.
Then stacktrace looked like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:589)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.drawPlayer(GameScreen.java:264)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.batchDraw(GameScreen.java:231)
at com.m2f.ninjagame.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:116)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Comment: Please show the entire stack trace. Animation can only throw "/ by zero" if the frame time is zero, which it's not in the code you showed above. Something else is going on. Also, do not use Sprites with Animation. Use TextureRegions. (Use `atlas.findRegions()` instead of `atlas.createSprites()`.) Sprites are heavier weight than TextureRegions, and Animation ignores the extra data.

Comment: stack trace added.

Comment: You must be setting the Animation's frame duration to zero somewhere in code that you're not showing. As for the NPE...you are trying to draw a null texture region or texture instead of an actual one.

Comment: Frame duration is there.animTime += delta; inside render()

Comment: That's not frame duration, that's elapsed time. It's set in the constructor or in `setFrameDuration()`