# Division By Zero Exception caused by animation key frame (LIBGDX)

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, textures

Basically, I tried implementing an animation in one of my game's screens using a TextureAtlas and using .findRegions() to use for the animation object.

I tried renaming the files to their respective indices (as well as updating the .pack folder)

```
Sample Pack Folder:

sunglasses_1.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
tile000
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 600, 600
  orig: 600, 600
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
...and so on until sunglasses_35.png
```

I've also read about the same issue in SAO here: [Animating the sprite array created from texture atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974373/animating-the-sprite-array-created-from-texture-atlas) - however it did not help. I've also read the GitHub page including information about Animations and TextureRegions.

Here are the lines of code that were used to implement an animation

**Animation setup**

```java
//animation setup with batch
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        animationAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("sunglasses.pack"));
        animation = new Animation<>(0.13f, animationAtlas.findRegions("sunglasses"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

**Animation called in the render() function from the Screen class**

```java
  @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), 100, 100);
        batch.end();
    }
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrameIndex(Animation.java:138)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrame(Animation.java:122)
    at com.tantei.game.Screens.MainMenu.render(MainMenu.java:104)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.tantei.game.Game.render(Game.java:21)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Any help is appreciated!!

**[EDIT]** `animation.getKeyFrames()` returns a size of 0 - hence the exception. I still don't get why it has no elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your atlas is not created correctly for an animation, so when you call `animationAtlas.findRegions`, it's returning an empty array. When you call `animation.getKeyFrame()`, it is dividing by zero frames of animation, hence the exception.

For `animationAtlas.findRegions("sunglasses")` to work, your regions in the pack file would each need the exact same name (sunglasses), not  tile000, tile001, tile003, etc. And they should each have a different `index` under them, not all have an `index` of -1.

Trying to create a texture atlas manually is just punishing yourself. Use TexturePacker.